# Is this question asked correctly?

Tags: sentence-construction

I saw someone post a tweet with a gif animation (a rock star singing something). The tweet itself is about some stock's price going up or down.

Every comment under that tweet is talking the stock price. And I want to post a comment to ask who is that rock star and which song is him singing.

Well, I want to ask with a little sense of humor.

Can I say,

> "Am I the only one who wants to know what music video is in this gif?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grammatically, the sentence is OK.

However, you might receive some answers with "a little sense of humor" too:

> - Yes, you are the only one.
> - No, you are not he only one.

And in the end, you still do not know anything about the band or about the song.

---

It would be more helpful to ask:

> - What's the name of the song in the video?
> - What is the name of the band performing?

---

Not English related, but related to the content of the question: while the video is playing, use an online service like Shazam to identify details about the song: title, band...

Comment: Awesome tips. Thanks!